# background image not loading from other folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background

I am facing an problem while adding background image to paragraph when I use **URL** of other folder it does not load pic
background-image:url('C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\pic2.png');
while using like that pic in same folder of file it loads

> ```
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
>     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
>     <title>Height ,width,border and backgrounds</title>
>     <style>
>         #firstPara{
>             background-color: cadetblue;
>             height:70px ;
>             width:200px ;
>             /* Write together */
>             border-width: 3px;
>             border: 4px solid blue;
>             /* write alone */
>             /* border-color: green;
>             border-style:solid; */
>             border-radius: 6px;
>         }
>         #secondPara{
>             background-color: rgb(211, 111, 220);
>             height:70px ;
>             width:200px ;
>             /* Write together */
>             border-width: 3px;
>             border: 4px solid rgb(163, 234, 40);
>            border-top-left-radius: 5px;
>            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
>            border-left-color: black;
>            border-bottom-color: cadetblue;
>            border-right-color: burlywood;
>            border-left-style: double;
>         }
>         #thirdPara{
>            
>             height:600px ;
>             width:200px ;
>             /* this one wont work if use pic from desktop */
>            background-image:url(C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\pic2.png);
>
>            /* below one works when image located in same folder */
>            /* background-image:url(pic2.png); */
>         }
>     </style>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <h3>This is heading</h3>
>     <p id="firstPara" >This is a paragraph</p>
>     
>     <h3>This is heading</h3>
>     <p id="secondPara" >This is a paragraph</p>
>      
>     <h3>This is heading</h3>
>     <p id="thirdPara" >This is a paragraph</p>
>      
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes please do provide code

Comment: You are using C:\... you either have to specify the current folder, previous or root folders.

Comment: please checkout code

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have a folder structure like this

```
IamRootFolder
    index1.html
    IamFolder
        index2.html
    IamFolderToo
        index2.html
        css.css
```

There are three ways to define a path (for what i know)

```
/the-root-folder
./this-folder
../the-previous-folder
```

And not adding anything is the same as `./`.
so to access `css.css`
index1.html will need `./IamFolderToo/css.css`
index2.html will need `../IamFolderToo/css.css`
index3.html will need `./css.css`

Otherwise they can all simply use `/IamFolderToo/css.css`.
[W3 examples link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)